# Typesetting the document which fits into marked fixed lines

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, text-formatting

I have to typeset the article such as that the output should be printed on the fixed marks that are 1.36 cm apart.

In other words, the printing sheet has marked lines which are 1.36 cm apart. I have to type with font 11, or 12, which fits into these marked lines.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this, which i tried was type the matter in Excel sheet, and fix the cell height to 38.86 (which corresponds to 1.36 cm). Note: 1pt = 0.035cm. Copy the text and paste in word.

but, could not find the direct method to set the line space in word.